# What is the best way to test driver across multiple versions of windows?

Tags: windows, drivers

We need to test our drivers across multiple versions of windows, is it possible to do the following.

create 5 partitions on a 100Gb hardrive, 20GB each with windows disk management.

(1) Install Windows 8.1 – 64 bit
(2) Install Windows 8.0 – 64 bit
(3) Install Windows 7 – 64 bit
(4) Install Windows 8.1 – 32 bit
(5) Install Windows 8.0 – 32 bit

As I create the new partition and install see if I can boot from it.

I figure 8.1 64-bit needs to support booting the other versions.

Does anyone currently have a better way to do this, or has anyone tried this?
Regards,

-SS

Comment: Install virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to set up virtualized instances of the applicable versions of Windows if your environment allows for it.

If you are just limited to a single desktop workstation, then your method of creating multiple partitions and manually booting from each one to test drivers is a good "budget" solution.

If you are in an environment that has the computing horsepower to run the free version of VMWare or Hyper-V, you could spin up virtual instances of the workstations at the same time and access them through a console or through RDP.